# Creating pairwise cluster plot with histograms down diagonal (similar to FisherIris Demo)

Tags: matlab, histogram, classification

I have 8 columns of data and want to create a pairwise scatter plot like the one in the Kevin Murphy Book[image: .]

I was told there is code online to create this [found it here](https://code.google.com/p/pmtk3/source/browse/trunk/demos/fisheririsDemo.m?r=2800&spec=svn2800), but i dont see how it seems to cluster the data and i dont know how to adapt it to my data

Comment: What do your data look like? Can you show a small example we can work with?

Comment: Here is some test data http://pastebin.com/35Zbkyqa . The actual data is 392 rows.

Comment: Could you tell us what those 8 columns represent and which "pairs" you want to plot? Right now your first column is allways 8, your 6th column is allways 70, your 7th column is allways 1 and your 5 and 8 column are more or less the same entries... I have no idea what it is you want to do with it...